# Modify Chrome's startup command line options

Tags: windows, google-chrome, command-line-arguments

I managed somehow to install an insidious toolbar. It modified many of my browser settings but one is especially puzzling.

By typing `chrome://version` in the address bar I've noticed the following in the command line section:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end http://www.example.com/

How can I remove the `http://www.example.com/` from the command line options?

Comment: How are you starting Chrome? From a Windows shortcut?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes. But I've checked the Target of the shortcut and it's just the `chrome.exe`

Comment: What happens if you disable your extensions?

Comment: Which toolbar was it?

Comment: @DavidPostill delta home or something. All the extensions that are enables (3) are well known and trustworthy. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Is it "Delta Toolbar"? http://malwaretips.com/blogs/delta-toolbar-virus/

Comment: https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/8391-delta-homes-com-redirect-updated also has instructions for Chrome. I'm not sure if it the same toolbar. It says "If you continue to have problems with removal of the delta-homes.com (updated), reset your Google Chrome browser settings." and gives instructions for this. Read the whole Chrome section.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's the little bugger. Yup, tried resetting it. I think i'll have to reinstalling it. Checked through the registry keys and couldn't find the website. Pretth stumped. Thanks a lot for your time and help. I really appreciate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26137/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-user3371583).

Comment: @DavidPostill Well reinstalled Chrome. That seemed to work in the end. `chrome://version` shows just the `chrome.exe`. Again thank you for your patience. Pretty noobish regarding windows.